# How to get the top row from a SQL Server record set query and other constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL Server tables as below:

```
Event

+------------+----------------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| Id         | EventTypeId  | PersonId    | UCNumber    | Name       |DateEvent        
+------------+----------------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| 2307       |      3       |      2189   |   004947    | Migrated   | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.6780000 |
| 2308       |      15      |      2189   |   004947    | Birthday   | 2020-09-18 16:48:32.6870000 |
| 3400       |      15      |      2190   |   006857    | Birthday   | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 3401       |      2       |      2190   |   006857    | Migrated   | 2016-03-12 00:00:00.0000000 |


Person 

+------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+
| Id         | UCNumber       |      Name         |LastName   |  AnotherDate                  | 
+------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------------------+
| 2189       |      004947    |        John       |   Smith   |   1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 2190       |      006857    |        Alice      |   Timo    |   2020-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 |
```

I need to get retrieved the top row (latest in time) based on the Event's `Id`. (The higher the `Id`, the more recent the Event) and it should be a `15` as `EventTypeId`.

I tried this:

```
Select P.Id, P.UCNUMBER, P.AnotherDate from 
db.dbo.Person P
Inner join db.dbo.Event L on L.PersonId = P.Id
where P.Id in (
    SELECT TOP (1) PersonId
    FROM
        db.dbo.Event 
    where PersonId = P.Id --and EventTypeID = 15
    ORDER BY 
        Id DESC) 
and EventTypeId = 15
```

but it does not work properly. I posted here just samples from the 2 tables. Generally the query takes also other events which are not latest ones (as higher Id). Something is missing in it.

In this case, for instance, it should return only 1 row:

`2189     004947     1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want `ORDER BY` and `TOP 1`.

```
SELECT TOP 1
       p.id,
       p.ucnumber,
       p.anotherdate
       FROM event e
            LEFT JOIN person p
                      ON p.id = e.personid
       WHERE e.eventtypeid = 15
       ORDER BY e.dateevent DESC;
```

If you want all ties in case there are more events on the same latest time you can replace `TOP 1` with `TOP 1 WITH TIES`.

Comment: There are more than 1 person with different Events. For each person I need to check the where clause and select it. Do you mean to place your select as the sub-query ?

Comment: @Dalian: That doesn't make any sense. One cannot select a `WHERE` clause. Your question asks for the latest event(s (see the edit)) of a certain type along with the person data. That's what I answered. You only need that single query I showed, it's not meant to be a subquery. If you need something different you should post a new question and better articulate what you want there. Maybe a broader example (sample data and expected result) might help if you have difficulties explaining your needs.

Comment: @Dalian: You should not edit a question if the edit invalidates an already given answer. That's why I specifically wrote you should post a new question. (But still it isn't very clear what you want, so I'm afraid you really have to put more effort in it.) Please roll back the edits invalidating my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your query solution @sticky bit. I restored the question to its original form.